# Which classes need to be extended to change the price in code throughout the store?

Tags: magento2, price, extend

I'm writing a test module that should change the prices of all items throughout the store simply by adding some value (eg 10).

I've written the module and now I am trying to find out exactly which Classes to extend. I have successfully managed to change the Grand Total by extending

```
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Grand
```

and editing the `collect()` function to wrap the vars in my helper function `_rewritePrice()` prior to setting them.

eg: `$total->setBaseGrandTotal($this->_helper->_rewritePrice($baseTotals));`

However, I can't seem to find out exactly which Classes I need to extend to have it apply to all values throughout the store.

eg: Category View, product view, mini cart, cart, checkout, invoice and so it is correctly applied to tax values, refunds and so forth.

Is there an easy way to find out which I may have overlooked? Or does anyone know where I need to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I ended up writing a module that depends on Magento_Tax that utilised the new plugin feature (thanks to Ryan H.) in magento2 and used a `beforeRound` function from `Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation`, since the round function is called everywhere.

```
  public function beforeRound($interceptedInput, $price)
  {
    if ($this->_helper->isEnabled()) {
        $price = (...) // do your calculation here
    }
    return [$price];
  }
```

and in the di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation">
        <plugin name="Company_MyCalculation::beforeRound" type="Company\MyCalculation\Plugin\Calculation" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not start at the source, with an `afterGetPrice` plugin on `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`? Just take the given return value and add 10 to it.

See documentation on plugins: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

I'm not sure how that would take effect for coupons, special/tier pricing, etc, but it would certainly be effective for simply adding 10 to the base product price.